# Error while browsing deployed projects in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using Visual studio 2013 , ASP.NET

i tried deploying in my local PC and **browsing it**. It works perfectly!

But when i tried to **browse** the deployed program on the server PC,

The same program with same settings, it gave me this **error (in the form of a messagebox).**

**Visual studio Just-In-Time-Debugger
An unhandled Win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe[4992].
Possible Debuggers:
New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**

i tried everything i can think of. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check Event Viewer on server machine in "Windows Logs" > "Setup" part. The issue may caused by application pool used to run the site or something else depending what you've found in the event log.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto under the setup portion , i found nothing. As for the application area i found this "Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6001.18000, time stamp 0x47919413, faulting module OraOps12.dll, version 2.121.2.0, time stamp 0x54902933, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00014be4, process id 0x12c4, application start time 0x01d2be29aac16525."

Comment: OraOps12.dll is known as Oracle 12 DB library (and I see that IIS 7 is running by w3wp version number prefix), which I can guess that this is related to connection issue. Probably the app source mishandled connection somewhere during app cycle (open/close/dispose), check it first.

Comment: sorry i am kind of new with this. How do i check where the app source is mishandled? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Check your app code related with `OracleConnection` (include in your question if you're very suspicious about it). For some reasons it may require refactoring using exception handling (`using` statement, `try...catch...finally`) etc. to find source of connection issue. Also activate "Oracle Tracing" to ensure where the issue begins from.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i checked my codes. all is working fine with no errors. What else can i do to find the source of connection issue.

Comment: If you're sure all code base working fine, then watch for server machine platform: is it x86 (IA-32) or x64? If the latter is used, make sure "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is already enabled. Also you may check similar issue there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747092/oraops-crash-w3wp-exe-process.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i didnt receive that error anymore but now my program isnt retrieving data from oracle. The same settings is used on Local and server PC... the local pc is working but the server isnt retrieving anything. Is there anything i should be doing now?